# Using wildcard subdomain for Rediret URL in Slack OAuth

Tags: slack-api

Is it possible to use a wildcard in the redirect url for Slack application development?

I am trying to enter a redirect url that looks something like this:
https://*.SaasApp.com

Slack does not seem to allow the '*'. Is there a way to get Slack's OAuth implementation to permit replies to all the subdomains of 'SaasApp.com' in this example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to do it as of now. Why you need a wildcard subdomain, Pass your subdomain in the state parameter and when slack redirects to your redirect URL you can get the state back and redirect to the desired subdomain.

Comment: Yes, that would be my alternate approach. I'm just double checking to see if I have other options. As it feels a little less secure to be making an extra hop to get back.

Comment: Slack support has also confirmed there is no other options in Slack, and that they have no plans to add this feature.